# VOIP call notification in Background iOS using Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, voip

I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ios_voip_kit
its VOIP Calling Notification like what's app call
ALREADY Working

1. Foreground Notification is working in app
2. Setup VOIP Server code to send voip notification

Issue
VOIP Notification when app is closed, I think its something due to iOS 13 above restrictions that need to report CallKit before Pushkit but don't know how

1. Added background and voip capabilites
2. using APN and VOIP certificate on Server to send message
3. In iPhone console I can see some voip message received when app closed but app is not triggered

Comment: When you receive a voip push you must report an incoming call to callkit. If your app does not then it will no longer receive VoIP push notifications.